# GPIO access to members of certain group in Raspbian

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm dealing with GPIO in Linux Raspbian (Raspberry Pi). The thing is that root privileges are needed in order to actually use GPIO. Is it possible to make my user member of group, which has access to GPIO, so that I don't need to use su (or sudo)?

To give more context, I'm using Qt Creator, so I would like to execute Qt Creator with my user but also allows it to execute the app (which uses the GPIO).